# Meaning of "medicine bringeth double care when the malady is past cure"

Tags: meaning, proverbs

This is an excerpt from John Lyly 'Euphues: the Anatomy of Wit, does anybody know what does it mean?

> Search the wound while it is green; too late cometh the salve when the sore
>   festereth, and *the medicine bringeth double care when the malady is past
>   cure*.

Comment: Adding insult to injury? You aren't just dying, but you've missed an obvious salvation too.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

While I initially interpreted the phrase with a modern understanding of "care", as in *to tend to*, I did a check on the etymology of "care" to see if it could have possibly have another meaning and this is what I [found](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=care&searchmode=none) on Etymonline.com:

> care (n.) Old English caru, cearu ***"sorrow, anxiety, grief,"*** also
> ***"burdens of mind; serious mental attention,"*** from Proto-Germanic *karo (cf. Old Saxon kara "sorrow;" Old High German chara "wail, lament;" Gothic kara "sorrow, trouble, care;" German Karfreitag "Good
> Friday"), from PIE root *gar- "cry out, call, scream" (cf. Irish gairm
> "shout, cry, call;" see garrulous).

Based on the interpretation of care to mean *anxiety, burdens of mind*, I believe the 2nd half of the quote is saying that the medicine, though it "cares" for the wound, also brings worry and concern when applied too late.

Comment: Yes, "medicine brings double sorrow when the malady is past cure" is the only interpretation that makes sense.

Comment: I suspect that at the time this "homily" was written, it was commonly known that if you had a disease that couldn't be cured, you'd probably be subjected to all manner of highly unpleasant (but totally useless) "treatments". Medicine was so primitive it was really the equivalent of hitting a faulty TV with a hammer in hopes it might start working again. The final days of a rich man being ineffectively "treated" would probably not exactly be ***carefree*** back then; nothing like the way we use morphine and similar drugs in hospices for the dying nowadays.

Answer (score 10):

"*Search the wound while it is green*" means *probe the wound while it is fresh*.

The entire sentence is simply saying that we should always examine the wound while it is still fresh: if we examine it when the sore has already festered, it would be too late. And I think it serves as a metaphor.

My previous attempt to interprete "*the medicine bringeth double care when the malady is past cure*" was that medicine would bring twice the happiness when disease can be cured by it. But after checking with [EtymOnline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=care&searchmode=none) (should have checked with it earlier), I realized, as suggested by Kristina Lopez, care is indeed a negative word in the past when it is used as a noun, and thus the correct way to interpret the sentence is:

medicine would have brought twice the anxiety or sorrow when *the malady is past cure*, or, when it can no longer be cured (in a way *past cure*).

Comment: I agree with your interpretation of that part of the quote, but the OP is asking about the 2nd part of the quote, ***"medicine bringeth double care when the malady is past cure"***

Comment: @KristinaLopez I think it serves as a conclusion.

Comment: That's why I love this site, @yhcra, I think it is saying the opposite!  lol! :-)

Answer (score 7):

I believe that *medicine bringeth double care* is using "care" in the sense of "a cause of worry or concern", so the phrase basically means *You have twice as much to worry about*: when you thought that the wound was minor, you only worried about how long it will take until you get better.  Now that your neglect has caused a serious problem, you have to be concerned about surviving the treatment, living with a permanent affliction, etc.

Answer (score 4):

My interpretation:
When medication is started late in the disease process, it requires greater effort to treat ( hence double care ) when the disease has probably gone past cure (as a result of the delay). Something akin to "A stitch in time saves nine ".